# How often is unix time divisible by 10,000,000 seconds at midnight?

Tags: timestamps, time

I accidentally discovered that May 3 2021 was one of the landmarks of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Exactly at midnight (UTC) the number of `time_t` was divisible by 10,000,000:

```
$ date --utc --date='@1620000000'
Mon  3 May 00:00:00 UTC 2021
```

I'm not very mathematically inclined, so hopefully someone can explain the following:

- How often is unix time divisible by 10,000,000 seconds at exactly midnight?
- Does this phenomenon have a name?
- What are some other interesting Unix times?

Comment: This is a math, not a Unix question. the phenomenon is called "least common multiple", and it's elementary school math!

Comment: It's a math question about Unix. No need for the gatekeeping nor the insult.

Comment: Nothing particularly Unix-y in getting [the LCM of 10,000,000 and 86,400](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LCM++10%2C000%2C000++86400)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I wouldn't be so sure it gets taught in elementary school everywhere. Let alone that everyone would necessarily remember it. But, assuming it's elementary _to you_, one would expect that writing an answer would not have been too hard. At least not significantly harder than writing an unhelpful comment, no?

Comment: So you don't think it's off-topic, @ilkkachu? in that case, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a number divisible by `10 000 000` (or simply 10M) every 10M. That's factor 1.

You get to midnight every 24 hours (or 86 400 seconds). That's factor 2.

You need numbers multiple of 10M **and** 86400. That's a math function called L.C.M. (least common multiple). You can [get the result on this page](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/lcm.php).

That number is `270 000 000` (or 270M).

The first time that happened was at 0 seconds epoch (formally that could be in dispute). Or `1/1/1970 12:00:00 UTC`.

A short list of those events is given by:

```
$ for i in $(seq 20); do mult=$((i*270000000)); printf '%12s -- %s\n' "$mult" "$(date -ud @"$mult")"; done
   270000000 -- Sun 23 Jul 1978 12:00:00 AM UTC
   540000000 -- Wed 11 Feb 1987 12:00:00 AM UTC
   810000000 -- Sat 02 Sep 1995 12:00:00 AM UTC
  1080000000 -- Tue 23 Mar 2004 12:00:00 AM UTC
  1350000000 -- Fri 12 Oct 2012 12:00:00 AM UTC
  1620000000 -- Mon 03 May 2021 12:00:00 AM UTC
  1890000000 -- Thu 22 Nov 2029 12:00:00 AM UTC
  2160000000 -- Sun 13 Jun 2038 12:00:00 AM UTC
  2430000000 -- Wed 02 Jan 2047 12:00:00 AM UTC
  2700000000 -- Sat 24 Jul 2055 12:00:00 AM UTC
  2970000000 -- Tue 12 Feb 2064 12:00:00 AM UTC
  3240000000 -- Fri 02 Sep 2072 12:00:00 AM UTC
  3510000000 -- Mon 24 Mar 2081 12:00:00 AM UTC
  3780000000 -- Thu 13 Oct 2089 12:00:00 AM UTC
  4050000000 -- Sun 04 May 2098 12:00:00 AM UTC
  4320000000 -- Wed 24 Nov 2106 12:00:00 AM UTC
  4590000000 -- Sat 15 Jun 2115 12:00:00 AM UTC
  4860000000 -- Tue 04 Jan 2124 12:00:00 AM UTC
  5130000000 -- Fri 25 Jul 2132 12:00:00 AM UTC
  5400000000 -- Mon 13 Feb 2141 12:00:00 AM UTC
```

That is [the time as UTC (Universal Time Coordinated)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which doesn't show **Leap seconds**. That is a different time than [International Atomic Time (TAI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) and different than GPS time.

I am not aware that this events have been named (nor I believe they should).

There are some trivia at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Notable_events_in_Unix_time):

- At 23:31:30 UTC on Friday, 13 February 2009, the decimal representation of Unix time reached 1234567890 seconds.

Comment: According to the wikipedea article that you link to it is UTC that has the leap seconds. and TAI that does not.

Comment: @ctrl-alr-delor Nope. What that Wikipedia article says is that leap seconds are added to TAI to realize UTC. But the subject is way more complex. No way a correct description could fit into this coments.

Comment: Yes. I agree it is complex. I think it is important to realise that it is more complex. But most of the time this is enough. No need to understand it. However sometimes (if you are timing stuff that needs 1s accuracy)  you need to use a time source that does not do strange things. I also wonder if it can break the `make` build tool.

Answer (score 4):

I iterated over 0000000000 to 9990000000 and these are the dates that came back as divisible by 10,000,000 at midnight.

```
for i in $(seq 0 9);do for j in $(seq 0 9);do for k in $(seq 0 9); do DATE="@${i}${j}${k}0000000"; echo $DATE; date --utc --date=$DATE; done; done; done | grep "00:00:00" -B1

@0000000000
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
--
@0270000000
Sun Jul 23 00:00:00 UTC 1978
--
@0540000000
Wed Feb 11 00:00:00 UTC 1987
--
@0810000000
Sat Sep  2 00:00:00 UTC 1995
--
@1080000000
Tue Mar 23 00:00:00 UTC 2004
--
@1350000000
Fri Oct 12 00:00:00 UTC 2012
--
@1620000000
Mon May  3 00:00:00 UTC 2021
--
@1890000000
Thu Nov 22 00:00:00 UTC 2029
--
@2160000000
Sun Jun 13 00:00:00 UTC 2038
--
@2430000000
Wed Jan  2 00:00:00 UTC 2047
--
@2700000000
Sat Jul 24 00:00:00 UTC 2055
--
@2970000000
Tue Feb 12 00:00:00 UTC 2064
--
@3240000000
Fri Sep  2 00:00:00 UTC 2072
--
@3510000000
Mon Mar 24 00:00:00 UTC 2081
--
@3780000000
Thu Oct 13 00:00:00 UTC 2089
--
@4050000000
Sun May  4 00:00:00 UTC 2098
--
@4320000000
Wed Nov 24 00:00:00 UTC 2106
--
@4590000000
Sat Jun 15 00:00:00 UTC 2115
--
@4860000000
Tue Jan  4 00:00:00 UTC 2124
--
@5130000000
Fri Jul 25 00:00:00 UTC 2132
--
@5400000000
Mon Feb 13 00:00:00 UTC 2141
--
@5670000000
Thu Sep  4 00:00:00 UTC 2149
--
@5940000000
Sun Mar 26 00:00:00 UTC 2158
--
@6210000000
Wed Oct 15 00:00:00 UTC 2166
--
@6480000000
Sat May  6 00:00:00 UTC 2175
--
@6750000000
Tue Nov 25 00:00:00 UTC 2183
--
@7020000000
Fri Jun 15 00:00:00 UTC 2192
--
@7290000000
Mon Jan  5 00:00:00 UTC 2201
--
@7560000000
Thu Jul 27 00:00:00 UTC 2209
--
@7830000000
Sun Feb 15 00:00:00 UTC 2218
--
@8100000000
Wed Sep  6 00:00:00 UTC 2226
--
@8370000000
Sat Mar 28 00:00:00 UTC 2235
--
@8640000000
Tue Oct 17 00:00:00 UTC 2243
--
@8910000000
Fri May  7 00:00:00 UTC 2252
--
@9180000000
Mon Nov 26 00:00:00 UTC 2260
--
@9450000000
Thu Jun 17 00:00:00 UTC 2269
--
@9720000000
Sun Jan  6 00:00:00 UTC 2278
--
@9990000000
Wed Jul 28 00:00:00 UTC 2286
```

It happens every 270000000 seconds, which comes out to every 3125 days.

Comment: and of course 270 000 000 is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the two numbers involved, or 270 000 000 = lcm(10 000 000, 86 400)

Comment: Interesting: I did not expect it to happen anytime in my life-time. With leep-seconds. It should be out of sync, essentially random, and improbably. So it looks like leep-seconds are ignored, by Unix time.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, leap-seconds are ignored by consensus, see the last paragraphs of section [A.4.16 Seconds Since the Epoch](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_16)

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you're looking for the least common multiple of the seconds in a day (24·60·60=86400=2⁷·3³·5²) and 10⁷=2⁷·5⁷, which is 2⁷·3³·5⁷.

When you divide 2⁷·3³·5⁷ by the seconds in a day, you get

```
2⁷·3³·5⁷
-------- = 5⁵
2⁷·3³·5²
```

which in turn is simply 5⁵=3125 days.

Of course, reality is less smooth. If you consider the fact that "midnight" depends on leap seconds, you'll quickly notice that you'll have to define according to which way of counting time you're asking that question: UTC is not the same as GPS system time, and that might not be the same as the time displayed by your watch, and it's not the same time as Google uses internally¹.

---

¹ a lot of people applaud google for "solving" the leap second time consistency problem by "stretching" time over a longer period (a day). I personally abhor that: instead of implementing what's necessary to agree with everybody elses time, you fiddle with your clock. Everyone else solves that problem, at large scales: Google's self-proclaimed "planetscale" compute isn't that hard a synchronization problem when you compare it to what mobile network operators have been doing, globally, for more than three decades now.